# URL Encoded text not matching htaccess QUERY_STRING

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My website uses a comma to separate some coordinates in a parameter, like `?coords=38.88,-77.03`. I'm now finding issues as `,` is a url reserved character. The issue seems limited to when the links are shared with Facebook and Facebook changing it to `?coords=38.88%2C-77.03`.

Long term I'd like to fix it but I need to make a temporary fix for existing links that have been shared. If people were to click the link from Facebook I'd like an .htaccess rule to change it to using the comma.

I already have a similar rule for when there's a space after the comma:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*coords=-?\d{1,2}(?:\.\d+)?),(?:\s+|\%20|\+)(-?\d{1,3}(?:\.\d+)?,?.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1,%2 [L,NE,R=301]
```

I tried changing it to:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*coords=-?\d{1,2}(?:\.\d+)?)(,|\%2C)(?:\s+|\%20|\+)(-?\d{1,3}(?:\.\d+)?,?.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1,%3 [L,NE,R=301]
```

I cleared my cache and even tried changing the coordinate numbers to new ones, but I can't get it to redirect. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Your earlier non-capture group is not optional thus it is trying to match  1+ spaces after matching `%2C` and failing. You may use this rule:

```sh
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*coords=-?\d{1,2}(?:\.\d+)?)(?:[+\s]+|\%2C|\%20)+(-?\d{1,3}(?:\.\d+)?,?.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1,%2 [L,NE,R=301]
```